# Where are the program calls of the boot process stored

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, boot

I just wrote a little program which logs all calls of bash during the boot process. This is a part of the output produced:

```
(root) '/bin/bash-' '-c' 'gzip -d -c /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz'
(root) '/bin/bash-' '-c' 'gzip -d -c /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/../include/euro1.map.gz'
(root) '/bin/bash-' '/etc/rc.multi'
(root) '/bin/bash-' '/etc/rc.d/syslog-ng' 'start'
(root) '/bin/bash-' '/etc/rc.d/dbus' 'start'
(root) '/bin/bash-' '/etc/rc.d/network' 'start'
(root) '/bin/bash-' '/usr/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks'
(root) '/bin/bash-' '/usr/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks'
(root) '/bin/bash-' '/usr/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks'
(root) '/bin/bash-' '/etc/rc.d/netfs' 'start'
```

First column is the user, 2nd the program called (I only log bash here), 3rd column are the arguments.
Now assume I want to replace one of these calls: Where can I find them? I assume there must be some program/script/data file which has all these calls in it?!?

Comment: The boot process is very distribution-specific. Which distro are you using? What are you really trying todo?

Comment: Archlinux. What I want to do is to forbid the use of bash -c. Therefore I want to replace all -c commands during bootup with a simple shell script

Answer (score 2):

For Arch, the boot process uses `init`, which reads configuration from `/etc/initab`. Customization may also be made in `/etc/rc.conf`, but I think you'll have to dig into the init scripts specified in `/etc/initab`. See [Arch Boot Process](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Boot_Process) for more information.